# PHP SOAP request all lowercase

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have created a web service and have used soapUI to verify that it works correctly. However, the PHP client is getting a fatal error when attempting to access it.

I have a try/catch set up so that I can view the output SOAP Request and do a `var_dump`. When I view the request and `var_dump`, it shows it as all lowercase (even the custom header I typed the XML for manually).

I know XML is case-sensitive, and when I put the request back into soapUI and change the case correctly, I get the correct response from the web service.

What could be causing the SOAP Request to change to everything to lowercase?

```
//The WSDL url
$wsurl = "http://domain:port/mywebservice.wsdl";

//Custom header setup
$ws_username = 'myuser';
$ws_password = 'mypass';
$ws_authheader = '<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>'.$ws_username.'</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>'.$ws_password.'</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>';

//XML SOAP Security variable
$ws_authvars = new SoapVar($ws_authheader,XSD_ANYXML);

//SOAP Security header
$ws_header = new SoapHeader("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Security",$ws_authvars);

//SOAP client - trace is set to true so faults can be backtraced
$ws_client = new SoapClient($wsurl, array('trace'=>true));

//SOAP client parameters
$params = array('PARAM1'=>'123456',
                'PARAM2'=>'ABCDE',
                'PARAM3'=>'ABCD');

try {
    //SOAP response
    $messages = $ws_client->__soapCall('WSMETHOD',array('parameters'=>$params),NULL, $ws_header);
    //print_r($messages);
}
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    echo "\n";
    print_r($ws_client->__getLastRequest());
    echo "\n";
    var_dump($ws_client);
}
```

My __getLastRequest returns this (note that field values remain in their proper case):

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="mynamespaceurl" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <soap-env:header>
        <wsse:security soap:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:usernametoken>
                <wsse:username>myuser</wsse:username>
                <wsse:password>mypass</wsse:password>
            </wsse:usernametoken>
        </wsse:security>
    </soap-env:header>
    <soap-env:body>
        <ns1:wsmethod>
            <ns1:param1>123456</ns1:param1>
            <ns1:param2>ABCDE</ns1:param2>
            <ns1:param3>ABCD</ns1:param3>
        </ns1:wsmethod>
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

The exact SoapFault:

```
SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] null in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mydirs\mypage.php:458 
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mydirs\mypage.php(458): SoapClient &gt;__soapCall('wsmeth...', Array, NULL, Object(SoapHeader)) 
#1 {main}
```

The line it is indicating (458) is the $messages = $ws_client->__soapCall

Comment: The exact error message of your fatal error is missing. The message of the SoapFault is missing as well. Additionally it would be useful if you would add the XML of the last soap request to your question as well. From your code so far it is not clear how far that "everything is turned into lowercase" looks like nor in your code it's not clear what might cause it.

Comment: I added the SoapFault and the returned XML. It works now somehow, but I still have no idea why this was happening for the last 2 days. Other pages operated fine, but I found out they were not using SOAP to work with the web services.

Comment: Now this looks more like a question! Sounds a bit like a problem on the SOAP server, like returning an unexpected NULL. Probably the service was just not working properly. Not every SOAP endpoint is giving good error messages back.

Comment: I know that the SOAP server is not able to interpret the XML with the lowercase because soapUI gives me the same error message when I put the __getLastRequest in there. I'm just confused as to why and how either my soap client or soap server were changing it all to lowercase.

Comment: @DavidR. if the soap client would change it to lowercase, it wouldn't work for anyone. getLastRequest is not impacted by anything that server responds, either. My assumption would be that it is getLastRequest that changes it to lowercase on reporting.

Comment: That's very possible, but it doesn't explain the problem at all. When I capture the request and change the case to match the original text then send it on its way it gets the correct response.

Comment: having a similar issue. Apache 2.2 php 5.4. outgoing soapclient request casts all characters to lowercase before request transmission. Arg.

Comment: did you try to print_r(htmlentities($ws_client->__getLastRequest())); ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what causes this? I recently ran into this issue and it's clearly a bug in ext/soap somewhere which I am now trying to find and fix, but I have been unable to reproduce it locally so far. If anyone has a complete reproduce case I'd be grateful if they could pass it on to me. It's worth noting that whatever the root cause is, it still seems to exist in PHP 7.2.

Comment: @DaveRandom This has been several years now, but I believe the problem was located in how CodeIgniter was building the XML or the custom vendor library I was using to interact with the server. Whatever it was, I don't believe it was a problem baked into PHP. I wish I had thought to post why it wasn't working and how it got working...