# PHP soap request is all lowercase

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm trying to communicate with the DHL soap web service.
Via SoapUI i get all the correct data but when i'm using the PHP soap client i receive a soapFault.

if i check the lastRequest .. my entire XML is in lowercase, i have put this request into SoapUI and i receive also an error. This is because XML is case-sensitive.

```
$data = array(
    'DropOffType' => 'REGULAR_PICKUP',
    'NextBusinessDay' => 'Y',
    'Ship' => array(
      'Shipper' => array(
        'City' => 'Brussel',
        'PostalCode' => '1000',
        'CountryCode' => 'BE',
      ),
      'Recipient' => array(
        'City' => 'Paris',
        'PostalCode' => '75008',
        'CountryCode' => 'FR',
      ),
    ),
    'Packages' => array(
      1,
      'RequestedPackages' => array(
        'Weight' => array(
          'Value' => 10
        ),
        'Dimensions' => array(
          'Length' => 10,
          'Width' => 10,
          'Height' => 10,
        )
      )
    ),
    'ShipTimestamp' => '2013-11-30T17:00:00GMT+01:00',
    'UnitOfMeasurement' => 'SI',
    'DeclaredValueCurrencyCode' => 'USD',
    'Account' => '270835287',
);


$wsseToken = $this->wsseSoapHeader();
$client->__setSoapHeaders($wsseToken);

// Fetch response
$response = $client->getRateRequest(array(
  'ClientDetail'=> $clientdet,
  'RequestedShipment'=> $data,
  )
);
```

The wsse token is correct, because i can use that in SoapUI.
How can i send my request in it's original casing?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: it would help if you would tell which soap client you're using. what is $client?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using [SoapClient supplied by PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

As you can see from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258292/soap-client-call-not-generating-proper-xml), soapclient actually does respect the casing (and if it wouldn't, it wouldn't work for anyone). However, based on [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329069/php-soap-request-all-lowercase), I think getLastRequest() actually lowercases all XML when reporting it. However, your problem is probably something else.

If you're frustrated with the SoapClient, you can test for example [NUSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) instead. To me it's quite simple and reliable.